# Find 9 consecutive numbers in a string

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2017

I'm using SQL and I'd like to find occurrences of 9 numbers in a string.
Example:

```
String = 'Hello345 World857215297'
```

would return: 857215297

Comment: Which SQL engine are you using? MS Sql Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Other?

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for "using regex in sql", but without knowing which engine you're using it's hard to get you the right answer.

Comment: MS SQL Server 17

Comment: I think `patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'...` should work

Comment: @JamesZ, that only returns the position in the string where the 9 numbers start.

Comment: Yes, and then just take 9 characters with substring

Comment: I have tried that, but it returns unexpected results.  For example, the string (fstrData):  "02/10 BIT - warrant returned by gsmith" returns "02/10 BI".  Here is my sql:
SELECT substring(fstrData, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', fstrData),9) AS Number

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
I noticed a comment that reads,

> For example, the string (fstrData): "02/10 BIT - warrant returned by
> gsmith" returns "02/10 BI"

That is because PATINDEX is returning a 0 and therefore you are simply retrieving the first 7 characters in the string (position 0 through 7). You can add some NULLIF logic as shown below. Then you'll get a NULL back if 8 consecutive numbers don't exist in the string. You can leave it NULL or use ISNULL to handle the NULL as you wish. This should do the trick:

```
SELECT  String  = @String,
        SomeNbr = SUBSTRING(s.String,NULLIF(f.Pos,0),9)
FROM        (VALUES(@String))                                         AS s(String)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',9)+'%',s.String))) AS f(Pos);
```

**Returns:**

```
String                   SomeNbr
------------------------ ---------
Hello345 World857215297  857215297
```

Alternatively, you can use [patternsplitCM](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns) to identify any series of numbers and filter as needed.

```
SELECT  ps.Item
FROM    dbo.PatternSplitCM(@string,'[0-9]') AS ps
WHERE   ps.[Matched] = 1;
```

**Returns:**

```
Item
-------------------
345
857215297
```